# Update view relative to position of verticle UIScrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview

I was wondering how one would update items such as a UILabel when a scroll view reaches a certain point - I have a picker app in which the user scrolls a UIScrollView and the contents of the screen update relative to the position of the UIScrollView however I would like to know how to actually update the contents of a view, again, things like a UILabel relative to the position of the UIScrollView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `scrollView.contentOffset` to get current content position inside scrollView.